# Windows 10 Registry as a Database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, nosql, registry

I want to store data, around 200,000 key-value pairs.

I know the Windows Registry is frowned upon for this but bear with me, as technology has moved on...

If I store this in the registry, and my application is inside an App-V type container (it will actually be in a UWP container) - then the registry is local to my app.

So, only my app can access the registry, it is a subset of the windows registry (reduced size), and I have direct access (e.g it's not going through the File Access Broker of Windows 10).

Is there an issue with this?

- Performance? compared to what?
- Maximum size?
- Multi-threaded access?
- Corruption?

I'll be using .net 4.7.2 and C#. Alternatives such as SQLite mean adding components and building a DB, over the top for a KVP. Other thoughts are the esent engine, but that requires a .net wrapper.
Thanks

Comment: `is frowned upon for this` If you know this, why are you considering it?

Comment: Use everything else - even a text file would be better than the registry.

Comment: Is there a reason for the aversion to external components? SQLite's dependencies are small, & the effort require to create the DB would be trivial.  A DB is the best thing to use for a DB.

Comment: I agree with those above. A database will be your best performer and most reliable

Comment: @juergend - Can you detail why anything else would be better? is this an opinion or do you have a basis for your recommendation? - also a text file wouldn't be single record write, it's whole file write which wouldn't support multi-threads and is not efficient.

Comment: @AlexK. - Good question, my aversion is one of simplicity, why use a 3rd party DB when Windows has one built in - for my needs this is a single KeyValuePair DB which comes under NoSQL, so SQLite, for example, is overkill.

Comment: @mjwills - Most people's view of the registry is based on it being the central windows DB. However, moved on, in this case means we're looking at virtualisation, redirection, and containerisation of the registry, not the traditional viewpoint.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from doing it, its simply that the alternatives are better imo, for example there is no indexing support in the registry,  its only query capabilities are fetch-by-name or enumerate all, its not transactional, its not portable in terms of being easy for a user to backup and move ...

Comment: @AlexK. - Now we're getting somewhere :) - that's a good, well defined reason - no indexing (I thought it was). Okay, any thoughts on a good KVP alternative?

Comment: Personally I use SQLite for things like this.

Comment: @AlexK. SQLite is a very common answer, but it's not a KVP DB and a bit over the top for what I'm looking for. The advantage of KVP is the zero setup and easy use. SQLite takes a little bit more setup than I need - Maybe the ESENT engine is good; that provides an indexed KVP DB. I think now that I know the registry doesn't index means I'll need to investigate the alternatives. ESENT seems good, SQLite seems popular.

Answer (score 1):

A binary file wrapper with hard coded field sizes would work perfectly, but has the r/w bloat flaw. For that, move to memory mapped files, which are completely awesome and blazing fast (the reg hives are done that way fyi).

You could use pinvoke on `(Get|Write)PrivateProfile*.` functions. That ancient stuff still works.

On a general note, I see 3 motivations: read, write and change detect/notify.
For the first two, I confirm the registry is NOT good storage for state persistence, given the general load on it (check that out with sysinternals procmon filter 'Path contains HK', and watch who is hammering (`RegRead.*`) or tattooing the registry (`RegWrite.*`)).
Configuration storage is Ok of course, that being the original design intent of the registry.

Monitoring is another thing. This would be good, and would allow you to go event driven data storage.

See: [pinvoke.net](https://pinvoke.net) FindFirstChangeNotification.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I would point out though that the registry would be dedicated to the app as described, it couldn't be accessed aby any other service.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @AlexK. The windows registry, while it is a database, it's not indexed and therefore performance would be very poor. That's a great reason to not use it.

I will investigate ESENT and other NoSQL based KVP stores.

Thanks to all that posted.